# Chrome auto-fill & autocomplete=on not working

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete

I can find a lot of references even on StackOverflow that Chrome Auto-fill functionality should work if autocomplete="on".

However that does not seem to be the case with the latest Chrome I have here (60.0.3112.90). To be precise - default browser autocomplete works fine , but **Auto-fill** will ignore the field completely.

The code below won't work with Chrome Auto-fill:

```
<form method="post" name="checkout" url="/">
    <input type="text" name="given-name" autocomplete="on"   />
    <input type="text" name="email"  autocomplete="on"  />
</form>
```

However, this will work without issues:

```
<form method="post" name="checkout" url="/">
    <input type="text" name="given-name" autocomplete="given-name"   />
    <input type="text" name="email"  autocomplete="email"  />
</form>
```

You can easily test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/kw4yjpz4/

**Screenshots**: [image: Auto-Fill when autocomplete="on"]
[image: Auto-Fill when autocomplete="given-name"]

Does it mean that all input fields now have to have autocomplete="[NAME]" for auto-fill to work? Is this a bug in the newest Chrome or intended behaviour?

Comment: Pretty sure that the behaviour has changed so only the second example works - you have to specify they type. Don't think there is a standard for autofill, so google just does whatever they want?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this same issue and searching led me here... I moved on not finding an answer and finally stumbled across the answer to my cause of the issue, so I came back in case someone like me wanders through with the same issue (likely myself in 2 years when I've forgotten about it - hi, me!).

**Turns out if the site does not have a valid SSL cert, Chrome Autofill does not work.**

Try the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>The autocomplete Attribute</h2>

<form action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p>Fill in and submit the form, then reload the page to see how autocomplete works.</p>
<p>Notice that autocomplete is "on" for the form, but "off" for the e-mail field.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The above works as I want in Chrome when the site has a valid SSL cert.  Saving locally and opening the .html results in Autofill not working.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find this answer before stumbling onto the solution myself - took a couple of days before said stumble...

Answer (score 0):

autocomplete works once you submit the data see

https://jsfiddle.net/0x31Loo1/#&togetherjs=CtJMLzM7AP

```
<form method="post" name="checkout" url="/" autocomplete="on">
    <input type="text" name="given-name"  />
    <input type="text" name="email"    />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this question is about Chrome Auto-Fill, default browser autocomplete works, Chrome Auto-fill doesn't. Can you try the jsfiddle I provided and confirm you can get Chrome Auto-fill to show up the same way as it works on the second screentshot?

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete allows the browser to predict the value. When a user starts to type in a field, the browser should display options to fill in the field, based on **earlier typed values**.

The autocomplete attribute works with the following  types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, datepickers, range, and color.

And It contains only **on|off** Value for 'autocomplete' attribute.

In some browsers you may need to activate an autocomplete function for this to work (Look under "Preferences" in the browser's menu)

Comment: Thank you, but this question is about Chrome Auto-fill, default browser autocomplete works, Chrome Auto-fill doesn't. Can you try the jsfiddle I provided and confirm you can get Chrome Auto-fill to show up the same way as it works on the second screentshot?

Comment: Its working for me for both way but second way you use it is wrong.
And as i told earlier "In some browsers you may need to activate an autocomplete function for this to work (Look under "Preferences" in the browser's menu)"

Just double click on field and you will get result

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me which version of Chrome you are using? As you can see from screenshots it does not work for me for some reason.